# Of fibonomials, pellonomials, and tribonomials, etc

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

**I. Linear recurrence with order 2**

Given the *Fibonacci numbers* $F_n$, we have

$$\begin{aligned}
&F_n+F_{n+1}-F_{n+2}=0\\[1mm]
&F_n^2-2F_{n+1}^2-2F_{n+2}^2+F_{n+3}^2=0\\[1mm]
&F_n^3+3F_{n+1}^3-6F_{n+2}^3-3F_{n+3}^3+F_{n+4}^3=0\\
&\small\text{and so on.}
\end{aligned}$$

The coefficients are called *[fibonomials](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/Fibonomials.html#fibonomFormula)*. (The version for the *Pell numbers* are quaintly called the *[pellonomials](https://oeis.org/A099927)*.)

**II. Linear recurrence with order 3**

For the *tribonacci numbers* $T_n$, we have,

$$\begin{aligned}
&T_n+T_{n+1}+T_{n+2}-T_{n+\color{brown}3}=0\\[1mm]
&T_n^2 - T_{n + 2}^2 + 6T_{n + 3}^2 - 3T_{n + 4}^2 - 2T_{n + 5}^2 + T_{n + \color{brown}6}^2 = 0\\[1mm]
&T_n^3 - 2T_{n + 1}^3 + 2T_{n + 2}^3 - T_{n + 3}^3 - 14T_{n + 4}^3 \;\;+\;\; \dots \;\;+\;\; T_{n + \color{brown}{10}}^3 = 0\\
\end{aligned}$$

Notice that $3,6,10$ (and next is $15$) are generated by $m=\tfrac{1}{2}(k+1)(k+2)$.

> **III. Question:**
>
> Given a linear recurrence of order $d$,
>
> $$s_n = a_1s_{n-1}+a_2s_{n-2}+\dots+a_ds_{n-d}$$
>
> with $a_d\neq0$. Assume one can find a formula valid for *all* positive integer $n$,
>
> $$c_0s_n^k+c_1s_{n+1}^k+c_2s_{n+2}^k+\dots+c_{m}s_{n+m}^k=0$$
>
> with integer $c_i$ and positive integer $k$. How do we show that the *required* $m$ is a function of $k$ (and $d$) and in fact is a *figurate number*? Hence,
>
> $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
> \hline
> \text{Order}\; d&m&\text{Name}\\
> \hline
> 2&k+1&\text{linear}\\
> \hline
> 3&\tfrac{1}{2}(k+1)(k+2)&\text{triangular numbers}\\
> \hline
> 4&\tfrac{1}{6}(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)&\text{tetrahedral numbers}\\
> \hline
> \end{array}$$

**P.S.** I tested it with the [*Padovan sequence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padovan_sequence) $P_n = 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9,\dots$ (and others with 3rd order) and it has the same pattern,

$$\begin{aligned}
&P_n+P_{n+1}-P_{n+\color{brown}3}=0\\[1mm]
&P_n^2 - P_{n + 1}^2 + P_{n + 2}^2 - P_{n + 3}^2 - P_{n + 4}^2 - P_{n + 5}^2 + P_{n + \color{brown}6}^2 = 0\\
\end{aligned}$$

and so on. I also tested the *tetranacci sequence* and for $k = 1,2,3$ we have $m=4,10,20$ which are the first tetrahedral numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: this is more a sketch of a possible approach than a complete answer.

Given a general linear recurrence $x_n = a_1 x_{n-1} + \ldots + a_r x_{n-r}$ the solution is typically of the form $x_n = \alpha_1 \beta_1{}^n + \ldots + \alpha_r \beta_r{}^n$.

So if we consider $$x_n^k = (\alpha_1 \beta_1{}^n + \ldots + \alpha_r \beta_r{}^n)^k = \sum_{\lambda \,\vdash\, k} A_\lambda \left(\beta_1{}^{\lambda_1}\ldots \beta_r{}^{\lambda_r}\right)^n$$(where $\lambda \,\vdash\, k$ means that $\lambda$ is a partition of $k$, and the formulation of $A_\lambda$ in terms of the $\alpha_i$ is left as an exercise) we see that we can expect it to satisfy a linear recurrence.

Gaps in the argument:

1. I haven't covered the case where the characteristic polynomial of the original recurrence has repeated roots. I think this gap can be filled because that gives terms $\alpha_i x^j \beta_i^x$ which carry through to give similar terms in the new recurrence.
2. I haven't argued for the order of the derived recurrence.

Comment: I've generalized my question. I guess the hard part is to show what is the required value of $m$. (I've empirically observed they are figurate numbers where the variables are in terms of $k$.)

Comment: As a disclaimer, I only tested sequences where the characteristic polynomial has **no** repeated roots, so I don't know how valid my observations are (especially $m$ being a figurate number) if we include the case with repeated roots.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII, I would guess that being figurate numbers is a consequence of the figurate numbers being binomials; I can see how binomial numbers might be related to the number of different values of $\prod_i\beta_i{}^{\lambda_i}$ in the case that the $\beta_i$ are sufficiently independent.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way of phrasing Peter's proof that I think makes it less bookkeeping-intensive:

- Define the *Hadamard product* of two sequences $\{a_n\}$, $\{b_n\}$ to be the sequence $\{a_n b_n\}$.
- Note that the vector space of sequences forms an algebra under Hadamard product (that is, it distributes over ordinary addition and is compatible with ordinary scalar multiplication).
- Call a sequence *simple* if it is of the form $\{n^k \alpha^n\}$ for some constants $k,\alpha$.
- Note that the Hadamard product of simple sequences is simple.
- Note that a sequence is the solution to a constant-coefficient linear recurrence relation if and only if it is a linear combination of simple sequences.
- Conclude that the Hadamard product of two such solutions is also the solution to a constant-coefficient linear recurrence relation.
- Induct!

Alternately, see [these notes](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~pavel/gen_functions.pdf) for another perspective...

Comment: I've generalized the question. Is it possible to tweak your answer to derive the variable $m$? (Kindly see my comment to Peter's post.)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Short answer before I run off to dinner, which I'll probably update later: you can certainly use it to derive an upper bound for $m$, which will be the correct value in almost all cases. However there's the possibility of numerical coincidences. A possibly instructive example is given by the sequence $\{4^n+6^n+9^n\}$, which satisfies an order-3 recurrence and whose square satisfies an order-5 recurrence.